# How to represent argmax function for this graph?

Tags: functions, graph-theory

I have an input graph which looks like below.

[image]

I am trying to find a **partial injective function** for the above graph. So by definition of partial injective function, I can have unmapped nodes in my left side (for example `A5`). And by definition of injective function, I look for a one to one function that preserves distinctness. So some possible outputs  can be,

[image]

Now, I am trying to find **just one graph with the maximum weight**. How should I represent it in mathematical terms? To be more specific, I am trying to find **argmax** function or something of that sort.

Comment: Google maximum weight matching.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define the set of all possible choice before using argmax.  If your graph $G$ has two parts $A = \{A_1, \ldots, A_n\}$ and $L = \{L_1, \ldots, L_m\}$ and arc set $E$, then let

$$D = \{M | M \subseteq E, \forall i \neq j, (A_i, L_k) \in M \Rightarrow (A_j,L_k) \notin M\}$$

Then what you are looking for is

$$
\arg\max_{D' \in D} \sum_{d \in D'}  w(d)
$$

where $w(d)$ is the weight of arc $d$.